# Matching position and rotation of moving target.

Tags: derivatives, control-theory, constraints

So I'm trying to work out how to intercept a moving rotating target. The key is that that I must match both $x$, $y$ coordinates and the rotation of the target.

I'm a little confused, as this must be a very common problem in robotics/control theory but I can't find any relevant material so either it's non-trivial or I'm not using the right terminology in my searches. There's lots of solutions for matching positions, but matching rotation as well is much harder. I'm looking for pointers at either someone who has solved this before, or where to start in the literature.

**The setup**

More formally the equations governing your behaviour are:

1. $s(t)$ is your speed at time $t$
2. $\omega(t)$ is your rotational speed at time $t$
3. $\phi(t)$ is your rotation at time $t$. Therefore $\frac{d\phi(t)}{dt} = \omega(t)$
4. $x(t)$ is your $x$ position at time $t$. Therefore $\frac{dx}{dt} = s(t)\cos(\phi(t))$
5. $y(t)$ is your $y$ position at time $t$. Therefore $\frac{dy}{dt} = s(t)\sin(\phi(t))$.

We make the simplifying assumptions that standard acceleration and angular acceleration is instantaneous.

The equations governing the target position are:

1. $\phi_t(t)$ is the rotation of the target at time $t$
2. $x_t(t)$ is the $x$ position of the target at time $t$
3. $y_t(t)$ is the $y$ position of the target at time $t$

These functions are all known, so derivatives etc. can be calculated.

The constraints are as follows:

1. $x(0) = x_0$
2. $y(0) = y_0$
3. $\phi(0) = \phi_0$
4. $s(t) \leq s_{max}$
5. $\omega(t) \leq \omega_{max}$

**The problem**

Decide if there exist functions $w(t)$ and $s(t)$ such that there exists an intercept time $t_i$ such that $x(t_i) = x_t(t_i)$, $y(t_i) = y_t(t_i)$ and $\phi(t_i) = \phi_t(t_i)$ all hold. If there are such functions return those that minimise $t_i$.

**Thoughts**

I'd be interested in either how to go about obtaining either approximations or an analytic solution, or how to create some sort of iterative feedback controller that solved the problem. I'd also be interested in any easier special cases of target movement (moving in a straight line, circling a point etc.). I assume this must be solved somewhere as we definitely have drones that fly in formations!

Comment: If the positions (and therefore also velocities) are matched the rotation should also be matched right?

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen No, velocity is independent of position. Velocity and rotation are equivalent in the sense that each fully determines the other.

Comment: But if your reference velocity does not match the time derivative of the reference position then it will always be impossible.

Comment: If you and the target are at the same position, why does this mean that the velocities must match? (if we're considering velocity and not rotation). For example your velocity can be (1,0) and the target velocity can be (-1,0), yet you can both be at the same point in space e.g. (0,0).

Comment: You where referring to only one point in time, while I was (implicitly) referring to a period of time. But I am not sure in this case whether only using Cartesian coordinates would simply the problem because of the constraint on the rotation velocity.